# Async not working as I expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I've read all I can find on async programming in asp.net (c#). I've made sense of most of how it's supposed to work and when it should be used. Yet I find basic examples not working as I expect. Without `Task.Run` it doesn't seem to actually run asynchronously.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing in this example?

Say the code is like so

```
public async Task SubTask2()
{
    LongRunningOperation2();
    Response.Write("<br>------------------------ Finished -------------------------<br>");
}

private async Task<Boolean> LongRunningOperation1()
{
    int counter;

    for (counter = 0; counter < 50000; counter++)
    {
        Response.Write(counter + "<br>");
    }
    return await Task.FromResult<bool>(true);
}

private async Task<Boolean> LongRunningOperation2()
{
    await LongRunningOperation1();
    Response.Write("<br>------------------------ Long Task -------------------------<br>");
    return true;
}
```

Shouldn't `LongRunningOperation2()` return to `SubTask2()` and print "finished" before or while writing out numbers? Instead it prints finished at the end. Using `Task.Run` works as expected but then I don't see the point of ever not using `Task.Run`

Comment: `async` is not about running code in parallel.

Comment: Where is a call to `SubTask2` function?

Comment: There are no actual async operations in your code, the behavior you describe could probably be achieved by adding a `await Task.Delay` to your `LongRunningOperation2`.

Comment: `LongRunningOperation1` is *not* running asynchronously in your example.

Comment: all the code shown is synchronous code; `async` is *intended* for scenarios where there is something truly `async`  to do - fetching data from a database or web call, for example. It is entirely possible for a code with an `async` signature to *return synchronously* - and that is what is happening in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A design consideration of the `async`/`await` pattern is that sometimes code that has an `async` signature might return synchronously (immediately) - perhaps due to caching or local data buffering (reading data from a socket, perhaps, and having spare data left to consume from the buffer), or perhaps due to IoC etc providing a synchronous implementation of an asynchronous signature. In that scenario, the entire engine is designed to optimize by *not* doing anything as callbacks, but continuing to run synchronously. This is not an edge-case - recent C# updates have *extended* this by adding support for custom awaitables (in particular: `ValueTask<T>`) to *make this even more efficient* in the case when something completes with a synchronous but non-trivial result.

The purpose of async is to *facilitate* scenarios that have genuinely async components, freeing up the thread to do more useful things than waiting for an async operation to complete. It is *not* about parallelization.

In your case, all of your code is actually synchronous, so it continues to run synchronously all the way through.

Comment: So what you're saying is that it is really only meant for cases that are not dependent/happening within my code like a call to an api or something of that nature. That makes more sense if that's correct.

Comment: @Ranges exactly; out-of-process data fetching is so common in virtually all applications, though, that "only" is perhaps the wrong word

Comment: OK thanks for the clear up. It makes it a bit clearer. I've obviously got some more reading to do on  the subject but this has helped.

Comment: @Ranges yup; note: *if* you had called down into something that *really was* async (DB access via ExecuteAsync, for example) - then you would have had a different problem: because you didn't "await" `LongRunningOperation2`, from the web-server's perspective *that request/response is complete* - so when the async operation finished, it would have been writing to a dead response object, and would have failed. Very very occasionally (it is a thread race), CPU scheduling might have conspired to make it such that the DB access came back fast enough to have both threads fighting over the response.

Comment: which just means the code will have failed in a different and more exciting way; *even more rarely*, the async code might have managed to write it's output before the "finished" line got on the CPU and will have "succeeded" but with the upside-down result you didn't want :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you're missing `await` in `SubTask2()`, so it actually runs synchronously (waits for `LongRunningOperation2()` to finish).
Secondly, even with asynchronous execution, "finished" wouldn't be printed before `LongRunningOperation2()` finished it's work. The point of using it is to free the thread, so it can do some other work in the meantime (e.g. handle another request).

Comment: The OP has left out `await` *intentionally*.