# Is my understanding of async/await correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

from what I understand the code below should eventually retrieve the string `classification` while running other code.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreatePropertyAsync(Property property)
{
    string classification = GetClassification(property);
    // GetClassification() runs a complex calculation but we don't need 
    // the result right away so the code can do other things here related to property

    // ... code removed for brevity

    property.ClassificationCode = await classification;
    // all other code has been completed and we now need the classification

    db.Properties.Add(property);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = property.UPRN });
}

public string GetClassification(Property property)
{
    // do complex calculation
    return classification;
}
```

This should work the same way as in the below code from [Matthew Jones' article](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/using-async-and-await-in-asp-net-what-do-these-keywords-mean/)

```
public async Task<string> GetNameAndContent()
{
    var nameTask = GetLongRunningName(); //This method is asynchronous
    var content = GetContent(); //This method is synchronous
    var name = await nameTask;
    return name + ": " + content;
}
```

However I get an error on `await classification`: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'

I'm unsure why this is happening.

Additionally, according to [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) for expensive calculations I should instead be using:

```
property.ClassificationCode = await Task.Run(() => GetClassification(property));
```

Is this actually achieving what I want or is this just running synchronously anyway?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: kinda similar question from a few hours ago that might contribute to your understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47285836/23354

Comment: Note that that MSDN page is not about ASP.NET.

Comment: Your understanding of async/awat is wrong, but more seriously your understanding of Server side programming is also flawed. For async I/O, append to the await chain. For CPU bound work, do nothing or do it right: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string classification = GetClassification(property);
```

this is regular synchronous code; it will do nothing until `classification` is assigned. It sounds like what you want is:

```
Task<string> classification = GetClassificationAsync(property);
```

where `GetClassificationAsync` does something genuinely async in the middle and eventually populates a `Task<string>`. Note that if `GetClassificationAsync` still works synchronously, the code will all continue to be synchronous. In particular, if you find yourself using `Task.FromResult` : you probably aren't doing anything `async`.

Comment: What about the return type of `GetClassification` ? Shouldn't that be `Task<string>`

Comment: @Shyju if you mean `GetClassificationAsync` - then yes, it should indeed be

Comment: If GetClassification is only CPU bound you should not make it async, instead call it at the highest level with Task.Run => https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-even-in.html

Answer (score 0):

To have the same as in the code from Matthew Jones you have to change your code to

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreatePropertyAsync(Property property)
{
    Task<string> classificationTask = Task.Run( () => GetClassification(property) );
    // GetClassification() runs a complex calculation but we don't need 
    // the result right away so the code can do other things here related to property

    // ... code removed for brevity

    property.ClassificationCode = await classificationTask;
    // all other code has been completed and we now need the classification

    db.Properties.Add(property);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = property.UPRN });
}

public string GetClassification(Property property)
{
    // do complex calculation
    return classification;
}
```

But read https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html why not with ASP.NET